# Is there a way to publish Amazon Lex chatbots to Channels Beyond Mobile, Slack, FB, or Twilio SMS?

Tags: amazon-web-services, artificial-intelligence, chatbot, amazon-lex

Amazon Lex was an amazingly easy setup process prior to deployment to channels.  It looks like we can only publish to the following channels: Mobile, Slack, FB, or Twilio SMS. Are there any other options, for example, leverage the simple "Test Bot" (from the Bot Editor Menu) as a "no frills" Chatbot UI and embed it in an existing web page?

1. I don't want to limit to a Mobile platform, and I want to keep
   coding to a minimum.
2. Slack users must belong to my chatbot team. I'd like to deploy my chatbot to "the world"
3. Don't want to conduct business within Facebook
4. Don't want to use [Twilio] SMS messaging to conduct Chatbot communication

Any other deployment options would be greatly appreciated.
Best Regards,
Ian

Answer (score 2):

You can use SDKs provided by Amazon Lex to create your own client applications (Mobile/Desktop/Web). For example you can use [Javascript SDK](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/LexRuntime.html) for talking to Lex runtime service in your web page.

Answer (score -1):

The following AWS Labs project provides a sample Amazon Lex chatbot web ui:

https://github.com/awslabs/aws-lex-web-ui